# Store millions of data in mongo db using Springboot with rest api call efficiently

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, udp, blockingqueue

I'm working on Spring-Boot with rest api calls and Mongo database.
We have some hardware devices as the client and I am the server. multiple clients send me millions of byte data within milliseconds through the port and IP address(i.e) byte size is 4kb.

I am receiving that byte data through TCP/UDP server through port number. After that I am sending that data to my rest call with blocking queue concept and storing batch insertion data in the database.

Problem:

when client sending me 10 million data through the port and IP address (UDP concept) but my side receiving 5 to 6 million data only and 4 million data is missing.

I observed taking some time for data conversion (means byte data to int, float, boolean) and storing in DB at that time may be client data is missing

Comment: Since you seemed to fix it yourself, I did it now. Is "data" in your language same as "bytes" or how much is a million data?

Answer (score 0):

It’s too broad question and broad scope but just to give you an idea how you can solve your problem

1. If possible move to spring webflux with mongodb reactive, it will improve your performance because of non blocking io
2. You need to use load balancer for your micro services you created to consume records
3. Check your serve configuration and see how much load it can pick but of course webflux will help you in vertical scaling to consume resources but if load goes high use load balancer and deploy your app on multiple machines
4. Millions of records are fine in mongodb but you find performance degrading use mongodb on cluster.

This can help you to achieve what you are looking for.